# Why SQL statements do not work in table created in Oracle10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle SQL database with 2 scripts I uploaded to Oracle, one includes tables, the other includes the registries.

I have a table `DEPARTMENTS` with 2 columns, `CODE` and `NAME`.

From `Oracle 10g SQL home > SQL workshop > SQL commands`, I type in this statement:

```
SELECT CODE, NAME 
FROM DEPARTMENTS
```

The result is

> "No data found"

I cannot retrieve results correctly either in Oracle 10g nor in `livesql.oracle.com`.

Is my statement incorrect? Is it not retrieving the data uploaded?

Comment: Is the table empty? try select count(*) from table;

Comment: What do you mean by "registries"? Do you mean the actual data? (Perhaps you meant to say "records", which is still not technically correct, but at least it is a term understood by most people?) Are you sure you ran both scripts and they executed without error? If you have a "script" to insert data, it has errors, but the "script" is written in such a way as to hide errors, you may not even know that's what happened. Perhaps looking at that script would help. Is it an INSERT statement, or is that wrapped within a PL/SQL procedure?

Comment: Didn't Oracle 10g reach end of life quite some time ago?

Comment: "No data found" indicates that there is no data in the DEPARTMENTS table. Try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEPARTMENTS` to see how many rows there are in that table.

Answer (score 0):

Result should actually be "no rows selected", not "no data found".

---

You said you have two scripts; I presume that one of them contains something like this:

```
SQL> create table departments
  2    (code   number,
  3     name   varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Basically, you created an empty table. If you query it, there's nothing in there:

```
SQL> select code, name from departments;

no rows selected
```

Therefore, the second script most probably contains statements that populate tables created in the first script. Is that what you call "registries"?

```
SQL> insert into departments (code, name)
  2    select 1, 'Accounting' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Finance'    from dual;

2 rows created.
```

Let's repeat the previous `select` statement:

```
SQL> select code, name from departments;

      CODE NAME
---------- ----------
         1 Accounting
         2 Finance

SQL>
```

Right; now we got the result.

---

On the other hand, maybe you actually ran both scripts, created tables and inserted rows, but you didn't **commit** at the end of the second script. If you then opened a **new session** (in `Oracle 10g SQL home > SQL workshop > SQL commands`), then you saw tables (because `create table` is a DDL and it modified data dictionary so `select` you wrote didn't return "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"), but `insert` is a DML and you have to `COMMIT` - otherwise only that session (that ran `insert`s) will see data.

---

Finally, check whether `insert` statements completed successfully; if not, there's a chance that you didn't insert anything and will first have to fix errors. Which ones? No idea, I don't have those scripts nor saw the screen (or log file, if there is any).